# Safety of fixies

Tags: safety, fixed-gear

I am feeling minimalist and hipster, considering buying a fixie. I have never ridden a fixie and cannot gauge the safety of fixies (an important issue for me).

I am only considering fixies with *both front and back brakes*.

Does a fixie require proper training to be safe? Is a fixie any more dangerous than a traditional urban bike?

Comment: Not enough to warrant posting as a full answer: keep your fingers clear of the chain if the wheel is spinning while doing maintenance. You can slice off your finger if it gets jammed in the chain, an issue freewheeling bikes don't have.

Comment: You can still mess up your fingers on a freewheeling drivetrain, but you have to work way harder at it.

Comment: Also be very careful of shoelaces. Keep them out of the way of the drivetrain. Double knot them so they are not loose.  If they get caught in the crank or the front chainring, they can pull your foot off the pedals and make you eat pavement hard.  I ripped 6 lace holes out of a shoe and snapped my shoelace before I could stop while riding fixed gear on rollers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have brakes, then a fixie is no more dangerous than a single speed once you get accustomed to not being able to coast. Simply put, on a fixie, if the bike is moving, you *must* be pedaling. Take it easy at first and you will adapt to this quickly.

I would recommend spending a bit of time where there isn't other bikers/pedestrians when you first ride as a fixie.

I would recommend starting with a flip-flop rear wheel, fixie on one side and freewheel on the other, and carrying a 15mm wrench so you can flip it. As you start out on a fixie it can be more taxing on your legs than you might expect at first. Being able to change over to a single-speed (freewheel) and give your legs a break can be very important.

Happy Riding.

Comment: Thanks. Done, got one: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B007TH8LBC

Comment: Nice looking bike...you may want to skip the pedal straps for the first couple of rides.

Comment: Agreed. Also about coasting, agree with riding where you have some space, I also found that riding clipless pedals was useful. Because I was attached to the pedal, if I was tempted to coast it was only a fraction of a second before I felt it and was able to react/correct. With flat pedals (which I think are more practical in traffic), the only option I had was to just get my feet out of the way until I'd braked enough to regain control.

Comment: @KenHiatt I disagree that he should start off without pedal straps. Having your feet anchored to the pedals makes riding fixed a lot easier. http://sheldonbrown.com/fixed.html#pedals

Comment: NEVER RIDE A FIXED GEAR WITHOUT FOOT RETENTION. If you're not comfortable with the foot straps, then ride it freewheel until you get used to them.  The big danger is that your foot will slip off the pedal (especially when going downhill) and make it very hard to remount the pedals since they keep spinning.  It's hard to brace yourself for braking and maintain your balance with your feet off the pedals.

Comment: I disagree. If a fixie has brakes and you ride it sanely, foot retention is not a must...even if someone types in in all caps. I actually recommend speed plays myself, but consider straps and cages to be dangerous to the uninitiated.

Answer (score 7):

One thing that may be more dangerous on a fixie is performing emergency turns.  Since the pedals are always turning you need to make sure that your crank doesn't strike the ground while cornering.  Other than this I wouldn't think riding a fixie would be any more dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

After riding single speed for a long time I finally went fixed last week and there's no going back. Straps and toeclips: Absolutely. Not only are they more safe because as others have mentioned your feet won't be slipping off the pedal, they also fully connect you with the bike which is the whole point of riding fixed in the first place. Getting in and out of them is tricky at first dealing with the fact that the pedal is always spinning. I'm still mastering this, but it gets easier with practice. Take it slow at first, practice on a bike path or at a park. I would also recommend running front and rear brakes at first until you're comfortable on the bike and able to fully control your speed with pedal pace. When you get to the point where you're almost never grabbing the brake levers ditch the rear brake. 90% of your stopping power comes from the front brake, keep it for emergencies